# Is there a way to check whether NSManagedObject is freed or not?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

While I am working with CoreData there is an error:

`error for object 0x7fcadbb48b68: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.`

Indeed, I know why... I remove object which is displayed in my `tableView` from `NSFetchedResultsController`. To avoid this, I need to check is it freed or not, to not to remove it. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSManagedObject/managedObjectContext), you can check the 'managedObjectContext' exists or not.

```
if (YourNSManagedObject.managedObjectContext == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Hey I'm already freed, what are you doing with me. don't use me");
}
```

[image]